# Git corruption "unable to read [sha]" but git fsck reports no errors

Tags: git

I have a git repository with what appears to be a missing blob. A `git gc` or a `git repack` fails complaining "fatal: unable to read 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3". However, a `git fsck` does not find the issue. I know I'll probably have to delete and prune a branch somewhere, but I can't figure out where. Can somebody point me to how to debug and fix the "unable to read" issue?

git version is 2.16.4, but it is possible the corruption occurred in version 2.8.3.

The blob is not one that exists in the "offical" repo, so it likely just belongs to a local branch/reflog/etc. There are many local branches and

There are many worktrees on this repo, and it may have had worktrees added, removed, and pruned during its lifetime.

debugging information:

`git repack -adfb --max-pack-size=256m --window=40 --window-memory=100m
Counting objects: 5999778, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5983452/5983452), done.
warning: disabling bitmap writing, packs are split due to pack.packSizeLimit
fatal: unable to read 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3`

I've tried a few different fsck command-lines all with the same results:

```
$ > git fsck --cache --no-dangling --name-objects --progress
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (14155357/14155357), done.
Checking connectivity: 6003771, done.
```

.

```
git show 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
fatal: bad object 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
```

.

```
$ > git branch --contains 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3 --all
error: no such commit 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
```

This is a script I previously got off the internet for other purposes, but I though it might help:

```
$ > /tmp/git_blob_to_commit.pl 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
[no ouptput]
```

*Note that this is a huge repo so gc/repack operations take a very long time so if you give me some advice I am not ignoring it, I am probably trying it but it will be hours before I can get back to you with how it went.*

**Update**
re-running the command pressing [return] a couple of times and you can see that the error is not in the compressing phase. It is perhaps in the writing phase. (?)

```
Counting objects: 6006957, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5990610/5990610), done.
Writing objects:  19% (1193602/6006957)
warning: disabling bitmap writing, packs are split due to pack.packSizeLimit
Writing objects:  26% (1579434/6006957)
Writing objects:  63% (3802470/6006957)
fatal: unable to read 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
```

Comment: Do you have other worktrees (`git worktree list` is non-empty)? I ran into a bug in Git with added worktrees that produces problems like this. It seems some operations were not careful to scan hash IDs in the auxiliary work-trees and would prune objects that are still in use. (I believe the bug was fixed in between 2.8 and 2.16.)

Comment: Yes, there are definitely lots of worktrees in this repo. I will in fact update the question to say this because it's very relevant.

Comment: @torek, do you have any tips on how to diagnose/recover from that bug?

Comment: does `git config fsck.skipList` print anything?

Comment: In my particular case I did not need the extra work-trees, so I tossed them and Git was happy again. Not a good general way to proceed...

Comment: @max630, no, nothing in that config.

Comment: @torek do you have any ideas about what other debug I might do?

Comment: I had given up long before this point with my own setup, but: check the .git/worktrees directory, find any raw hashes in HEAD files there (probably none); and use `git ls-files --stage` on each index for each work-tree, to see if it's a blob hash in an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky scenario where older versions of git would incorrectly prune objects that were actually in use by the index on a worktree.

Here is the rough approach that I took. It could surely be optimized, but I hope to never have to do it again.

```
for i in $(git worktree list | awk '{print $1}')
do
    cd $i
    echo "TITLE $i"
    git ls-files --stage
done  >> /tmp/blobs.txt         # This is potentially a massive file

for i in $(cat /tmp/blobs.txt | awk '{print $2}')  # Brute force, could be optimized
do
    git show $i >/dev/null || echo "NOT FOUND $i"
done
```

For each "NOT FOUND" entry, run `egrep "TITLE|<sha>" /tmp/blobs.txt` to find the worktree it's in.
Then go to the worktree and unstage anything in the index. That should fix the problem(s).

---

Thanks @torek for providing the information to get to this conclusion. (You have enough SO reputation that I don't think you'll mind not getting the points for this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
git repack -adfb --max-pack-size=256m --window=40 --window-memory=100m
...
Compressing objects: 100% (5983452/5983452), done.
...
fatal: unable to read 89a9259486af9e3f0b24f3338ec39b18a7ba39c3
```

it looks like the object is unreferenced from anywhere, otherwise you would not pass the "Compressing" phase, and the failure happens during cleaning objects. You could verify it with running fsck with `--dangling` and `--unreachable` - it would print it in the list or even fail on it.

Comment: In my particular case the object was referenced either from a worktree index or from a worktree head, I think (I'm not quite sure since removing all my auxiliary worktrees wiped all of these out). The actual underlying reflogs and references are shared; it's the individual HEAD files and index files that aren't, and there was a fix to `git gc` some time in the not too distant past to make sure it scanned aux worktrees, so there must have been some Git versions that did not.

Comment: @max630: Thanks. It's not in the compressing phase. See my update to the original question, above. I've re-run the `fsck` with `--dangling` and `--unreachable` as you suggested and there are indeed dangling and unreachable blobs/commits/trees, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with that information. Before the `fsck`, I'd already done `git prune --expire=1.day -v` on the repo.

Comment: @max630 do you have any ideas about what other debug I might do?